# Bot Framework v4 - Check is user is logged in

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, botframework, microsoft-teams

When user chats with bot on the Ms Teams channel, how to check if he is logged in or not ? I have login part working the user is logged in but the problem is that Dialog does not end. After login process is finished and the message "You are now logged in" is displayed I want to end this dialog and never run it again unless there is no token. At the moment after the login is successful that message is being displayed along with my ordinary code every time I ask bot a question.

I have tried using Bot State to create user profile with Boolean variable that sets false/true if logged in.

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Get the state properties from the turn context.
    var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
    var userProfile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());
    // Check if user is loogen in if not run Auth Dialog
    if (userProfile.isLoggedIn == false)
    {
        // Call the MainDialog to display OAuth
        await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
        // Set the flag to true - user is logged in
        userProfile.setLoggedUser = true;
    }


}

public override async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    if (turnContext?.Activity?.Type == ActivityTypes.Invoke && turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == "msteams") {
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("You are using MS Teams.");
        await Dialog.RunAsync(turnContext, ConversationState.CreateProperty<DialogState>(nameof(DialogState)), cancellationToken);
        await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    } else {
        await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
        // Save any state changes that might have occured during the turn.
        await ConversationState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
        await _userState.SaveChangesAsync(turnContext, false, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

My Dialog class

```
public MainDialog(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<MainDialog> logger)
            : base(nameof(MainDialog), configuration["ConnectionName"])
        {
            _logger = logger;

            AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
                nameof(OAuthPrompt),
                new OAuthPromptSettings
                {
                    ConnectionName = "Conn Name",
                    Text = "Please login",
                    Title = "Login",
                    Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login
                }));

            AddDialog(new TextPrompt(nameof(TextPrompt)));

            AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
            {
                PromptStepAsync,
                LoginStepAsync

            }));

            // The initial child Dialog to run.
            InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog);
        }


private async Task<DialogTurnResult> PromptStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;

    if (tokenResponse != null) {
        return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
    } else {
        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
    }
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> LoginStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Get the token from the previous step. Note that we could also have gotten the
    // token directly from the prompt itself. There is an example of this in the next method.
    var tokenResponse = (TokenResponse)stepContext.Result;
    // if token exists
    if (tokenResponse != null) {
        // welcome user
        await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You are now logged in."), cancellationToken);
        // Display the name 
        await OAuthHelpers.ListMeAsync(stepContext.Context, tokenResponse);
        // End and return to the bot onMessageActivity
        //return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
        return await stepContext.CancelAllDialogsAsync();
    }

    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Login was not successful please try again."), cancellationToken);
    return await stepContext.EndDialogAsync();
}
```

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public bool isLoggedIn = false;

    public bool setLoggedUser
    {
        get { return isLoggedIn; }
        set { isLoggedIn = value; }
    }
}
```

Expected result:
User say Hi, bot returns Login OAuth dialog. User is logged in and welcomed with message coming from OAuth dialog. User asks question and the flow of conversation goes to onMessageActivity and never to the dialog unless there is no token.

Comment: Are you using OAuth Card for Authentication? Can you please share a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT I have added a screenshot. The messages "You are now logged in"  and "Welcome" are being displayed after every question that I ask the bot. I want this message to be displayed only once when user logs in. This messages comes from OAuth dialog in the second waterfall step. Anything I have tried I cant stop them from displaying.

Comment: @mdrichardson - MSFT could you advice what else I could try to get it sorted? Can you see any mistake I am making in my code. Thanks

Comment: (not mrichardson, sorry) Can you post your whole dialog class? I'd like to see how the waterfall is being constructed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply @JJ_Wailes 
My Dialog class has only two steps as per the first post. I have added the constructor code.

Comment: Can you show where that initial 'welcome' is coming from?

Comment: @JJ_Wailes To start any conversation I have to send message first to the bot so the first message I have sent was "Hi" that goes to "DispatchToTopIntentAsync" gets into switch statement and matches intent called GreetUser that returns the first message "Hi, I can... " and that's all this method does. This is only after "Hi" is typed in , at the moment I am treating this message as typing in "login"

Comment: Ok. In the image, that part that says 'Welcome REDACTED'. Find THAT in your code, and set the breakpoint, see what's triggering it.

Comment: I'm afraid that here comes the problem because behaviour in the emulator is as expected. The problem exists only in the Teams channel.

Comment: Yeah, whatever is causing this isn't in this bit of code. Can you link a GH repo, or email the URL to it to me at v-jewail@microsoft.com?

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I have managed to make it work. The problem was that in my constructor the UserState was created as UserState and inside the code I was using _userState. After making those changes the login works the way it should. Thanks